# Reading PDF from within an Android application

Tags: android, pdf

I am looking for a library/API that I wish to integrate to an Android application so that I can read any PDF files from within the application instead of using any third party applications!

By any PDF, I mean, say an Article in a magazine. I have the entire content of the article in PDF format. I would fetch the pdf from a server and download it into my device. Without using any external application like pdf reader, I would like to load this article.

Any suggestion on this is welcome!!

Thanks

Comment: Please define "read any PDF files".

Comment: Please check the solution I suggested here. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657136/displaying-pdf-pages-inside-an-own-activity/14657420

Comment: so which solution did you use :)

Comment: I used Android PDF viewer finally.

Answer (score 12):

Take a look into source codes of this applications on Google Code:

- [Android PDF Viewer](http://code.google.com/p/apv/)
- [VuDroid](http://code.google.com/p/vudroid/)
- [APDFViewer](http://code.google.com/p/apdfviewer/)
- [droidreader](http://code.google.com/p/droidreader/)
- [android-pdf](http://code.google.com/p/android-pdf/)

Definitely you will find which API/Library they are using.