# Open & Edit PDF files in Android App with APIs

Tags: android, api, sqlite, pdf, edit

Okay, this is the first time I'm handling pdf in android.

What I have:

- Editable PDF File with 2 pages (Forms to be exact, with brackets to tick, fields to comment etc.)

What I need to do:

- Store the PDF some where is the sd card (so that users do not need to download from any server)
- Allow users to open & edit the form
- Save the contents that was edited into SQLite

Problem now is that I do not know how to open the PDF file within my application & how to allow users to edit the files. I did see through this : [Reading PDF from within an Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646486/reading-pdf-from-within-an-android-application)

However, I do not know how to allow users to edit the PDF File. Would anyone please guide me? Thanks so much!

Comment: If the user isn't going to download the PDF file I assume that you're going to include it in the APK correct? If that's the case and, after editing, the results are saved in a database, why does the source need to be PDF?

Comment: @Squonk The original file given to me is in PDF. And because there are so much fields, with margins and etc, therefore I'm thinking that it's better to stick to using PDF. Or is it a better idea to like recreate the form in the application using TextView, RadioButtons & etc? 

Just to add, there is an option to upload the form into dropbox, and for that to be so, the saved form items would be converted and sent as a PDF too.

Comment: Well yes, my initial thought was as it is being distributed with the app, it may be better to create the forms using Android layout files. In this way, you will be giving the users an Android UX look and feel. You could also create different layouts for different screen sizes and so on. I suppose it depends on the actual purpose of the forms however and what your app does. As for the upload to Dropbox, a file containing XML data or even JSON would be more efficient perhaps but obviously would need something at the remote end to visualize the raw data. Just a thought.

Comment: @Squonk thanks for the information given, I will try it out to see if it works better.

Answer (score 2):

It is open source and built for unix/debian Linux so it will require some toying with, but it is a start.

http://pdfedit.cz/en/index.html

Comment: Have you used the library? Is yes, Can you please tell how to integrate it in android?

Comment: I have not, but honestly it looks like it may have fallen into disrepair. The last bugfix was in 2012, so it may be best to look elsewhere. Here might be a good place to start http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518954/android-api-to-read-and-edit-pdf

Answer (score 2):

you can use SDKs like Foxit [here..](https://developers.foxitsoftware.com)

and another way is libraries like [Qoppa](http://qoppa.com) pdf or [MuPdf](http://mupdf.com) are free