# Android API to read and edit PDF

Tags: android

I want to know if there is an API available for editing PDF files and save in android. This problem is not related to opening or reading a pdf file. Currently available APIțs wont give a way to edit the PDF file.

Comment: maybe https://pspdfkit.com/ is worth to try, but it is not free

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can try [Qoppa Android PDF Toolkit](http://www.qoppa.com/android/). Its not free though!

Answer (score 1):

you can use third party java libray [PDF Clown](http://www.stefanochizzolini.it/en/projects/clown/features.html). According to their site it has the following features

> - PDF generator: PDF Clown can create new PDF files
> - PDF reader: PDF Clown can access existing PDF files
> - PDF editor: PDF Clown can manipulate existing PDF files

Comment: according to source code it is not possible to use it on android ... it using awt, there is no awt classes on android